# MS Access changing reference path to a no longer existing path

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

When I compile a MS Access 2003 app on Windows 7 SP1 64bit and launch it in Windows 7 SP1 32bit the Microsoft Common Dialog Control 6.0 (SP3) path changes from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.ocx` to `\\shared\access\comdlg32.ocx` which is the shared drive the app launches from for Windows 7 SP1 32bit users.

I need the reference on 32bit machines to be:  `C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.ocx`

The 32bit machine errorors out on : `Dim Cnxn As ADODB.Connection
    Set Cnxn = New ADODB.Connection` But when the Common Dialog Control is referenced correctly by downloading the app to the 32bit machine, browsing for the comdlg32 file, adding it as a reference, and recompiling, the app works fine on the 32bit pc.

What does the Common Dialog Control have to do with ADODB?
I don't think I use the Microsoft Common Dialog Control anywhere. I will do more testing...

Comment: For what purpose are you using the reference, maybe  you dont use it at all and can just get rid off it...

Comment: @Arnoldiusss When I remove it I get the Runtime error: Class does not support Automation.

Comment: is Comdlg32.OCX installed and registered?

Comment: Which version of Access are you using that you require the common dialog control, because AFAIK, it is not a good idea?

Comment: Comdlg32 is registered on the windows 7 64bit machine. I haven't checked in the 32bit machine. If I compile the access app on the 32bit machine it references correctly and works. But I don't want to do this since it is the users pc. Access 2003 SP3 11.8321.8333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference has nothing to do with ADODB.

The test to see if you are using it is simple: remove the reference.  If the project fails to compile, then the reference was in use.

If you are not using the reference, remove it, and your problem is solved.  If you *are* using the reference, you can replace its functionality with Windows API calls, as Arnoldiusss suggested.

Comment: It is by no means impossible that the functionality is available already in more recent versions of Access. The example cited by Arnoldiusss was necessary in Access '97 but not in 2003.

Comment: @Remou if you're referring to the Access `FileDialog`, that doesn't work in runtime applications (and every Access project I've ever worked on professionally was distributed as a runtime application).

Comment: I have just tested with Access 2010 accde and the /runtime switch and application.filedialog seemed to worked fine.

Comment: That may be.  I am pretty sure it's not available for mde databases in Access 2003, however, and the question is tagged for that version.  Though I am fairly sure I have tested it, that would have been 5 or more years ago, and I'm not at work now (where I have access to Access 2003) so I can't repeat the test.

Comment: Filedialog works just fine in Access 2003 runtime, and I deployed applications to MANY people using this feature. It was added in 2003. And with the 64 bit version of Access 2010, you have to modify your api for 64 bits, so for access 2003 all the way up to 2010, I recommend use of file dialog (and I recommend using it as late bound). I would recommend the api, but since Access 2010 now have a true 64 bit version, then you need to maintain two versions, or at the very least re-write and change the 32 bit api call to a 64 bit call.

Answer (score 1):

If u use it for a filedialog remove the reference and replace it with the solution in this article:

http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0001.htm

EDIT: This should also work in newer version because it's just a way to get around using the comdlg32.ocx control.

You get the ADODB error because that is another reference, when the comdlg32.ocx fails to load Access exits the loop of loading the references, so the ADODB component isn't loaded.

Another option you could try is remove the reference and using late binding for example

```
Dim fDialog As Object ' previous Office.FileDialog
Set fDialog = CreateObject("Office.FileDialog")
```